# Control field visibility depending on User role

Tags: json, rest, go, annotations, response

I'd like to hide/show some fields of a model depending on User role.

What would be the most idiomatic way to implement it?

I don't really want to create N different types of the same model (where N is amount of User roles). Like: 
UserEmployee, AdminEmployee, WhateverEmployee.

It would be perfect if there is some solution that uses the tags for it:

```
type Employee struct {
   ID string `visibility:"admin,user"`
   Name string `visibility:"admin,user"`
   Salary int `visibility:"admin"`
}

jsonBytes, _ := someLib.Marshal(Employee{"1", "John", 5000}, "user")

fmt.Println(string(jsonBytes)) // {"id":"1","name":"John"}
```

The question is really pretty broad. I just wanted to know how you handle this situation or what is the most common way to do it in the Go community. I want clean and centralized (same for all models) solution that won't require to produce tons of duplicated code.

What have I tried before: I've just tried to use separate models for all cases and cast between them.

Comment: You could certainly implement something that uses tags that way to adjust what's rendered to the user. Creating multiple structs is unnecessary. Unfortunately the question "how to implement" something is too broad to answer effectively on StackOverflow; can you explain what you've tried, what result was expected, and what result you got?

Comment: I recommend you look into the reflect package (https://godoc.org/reflect), specifically the StructField and StructTag types. If you have the Go Programming Language book, check out chapter 12.7 - Accessing Struct Field Tags.

Comment: Thanks @Conner! I'll take a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create an empty struct of your type (Employee in this problem) that will hold the filtered data.
2. Use the [reflect](https://godoc.org/reflect) package to compare if the field tag contains the desired tag value (visibility role).
3. Copy values of base struct to our filter struct when we find a tag match and [json marshal](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Marshal) the output struct:

---

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
)

type Employee struct {
    ID       string          `visibility:"admin, hr, user" json:"id,omitempty"`
    Name     string          `visibility:"admin, hr, user" json:"name,omitempty"`
    Salary   int             `visibility:"admin, hr" json:"salary,omitempty"`
    Password string          `visibility:"admin" json:"password,omitempty"`
    Rights   map[string]bool `visibility:"admin" json:"rights,omitempty"`
    Boss     *Employee       `visibility:"admin, hr" json:"boss,omitempty"`
}

func filterEmployee(emp Employee, role string) Employee {
    var fEmployee Employee
    ev := reflect.ValueOf(emp)
    et := reflect.TypeOf(emp)

    // Iterate through each field within the struct
    for i := 0; i < ev.NumField(); i++ {
        v := ev.Field(i)
        t := et.Field(i)
        roles := t.Tag.Get("visibility")

        if strings.Contains(roles, role) {
            switch i {
            case 0: // ID
                fEmployee.ID = v.String()
            case 1: // Name
                fEmployee.Name = v.String()
            case 2: // Salary
                fEmployee.Salary = int(v.Int())
            case 3: // Password
                fEmployee.Password = v.String()
            case 4: // Rights
                fEmployee.Rights = v.Interface().(map[string]bool)
            case 5: // Boss
                fEmployee.Boss = v.Interface().(*Employee)
            }
        }
    }
    return fEmployee
}

func main() {

    e := Employee{
        "1",
        "Jack",
        100000,
        "password321",
        map[string]bool{"create": false, "update": false},
        &Employee{
            "2",
            "John",
            120000,
            "pwd",
            map[string]bool{"create": true, "update": true},
            nil,
        },
    }

    fuser := filterEmployee(e, "user")
    fhr := filterEmployee(e, "hr")
    fadmin := filterEmployee(e, "admin")

    buser, err := json.MarshalIndent(fuser, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Filtering with role user: ")
    fmt.Println(string(buser))

    bhr, err := json.MarshalIndent(fhr, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("\nFiltering with role hr: ")
    fmt.Println(string(bhr))

    badmin, err := json.MarshalIndent(fadmin, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("\nFiltering with role admin: ")
    fmt.Println(string(badmin))
}
```

---

Output:

```
Filtering with role user: 
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Jack"
}

Filtering with role hr: 
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Jack",
  "salary": 100000,
  "boss": {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "John",
    "salary": 120000,
    "password": "pwd",
    "rights": {
      "create": true,
      "update": true
    }
  }
}

Filtering with role admin: 
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Jack",
  "salary": 100000,
  "password": "password321",
  "rights": {
    "create": false,
    "update": false
  },
  "boss": {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "John",
    "salary": 120000,
    "password": "pwd",
    "rights": {
      "create": true,
      "update": true
    }
  }
}
```

---

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nc54-4trrQ)

**EDIT:** Updated answer for asker's request.

View the old playground for previous answer that ran into issues.

[Old Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8653vVokyV)

Comment: Thanks for the complete implementation! But could you please help me with how this solution should be updated to handle inner maps and inner structs? https://play.golang.org/p/Lo8Lx7YzBW

Comment: I changed my answer for you. I think this is what you are looking for and is much cleaner than my previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use "omit empty"

```
type Employee struct {
    ID string `json:",omitempty"`
    Name string `json:",omitempty"`
    Salary int `json:",omitempty"`
}
```

Your function can look like

```
func MarshallEmployee(e Employee, permission string) {
    if permission == "user"{
        e.Salary = 0
    }
    ....marshall it
}
```

or you could also just not add the value to the struct in the first place. See [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) for more detail.

Comment: That's a pretty interesting approach but we will have to abuse the "omitempty" tag. I'll try it anyway. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

use this module: https://github.com/icoom-lab/marian/

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/icoom-lab/marian"
)

type Account struct {
    Id   int    `json:"id,omitempty" role:"admin"`
    Name string `json:"name,omitempty" role:"admin,normal"`
}

func main() {
    account := Account{
        Id:   1,
        Name: "Jhon",
    }

    fmt.Println(account)
    // {id:1, Name:"Jhon"}

    marian.CleanStruct("role", "admin", &account)
    fmt.Println(account)
    // {id:1, Name:"Jhon"}

    marian.CleanStruct("role", "normal", &account)
    fmt.Println(account)
    // {Name:"Jhon"}
}
```

Comment: I get 404 from the link. Also, could you give some insight into why using the module helps with the question?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).