# Return JSON based on user role

Tags: json, rust, permissions, roles

How to hide/show some json fields of a struct depending on the User role?
We don't really want to create x different types of our struct. Or x types of an database user or multiple (same) sql commands.
Do you guys have some recommendations? Which crate fits there?
On Golang we used a reflect package to compare if the field tag containts the role.

The Export example should be equal like this:

```
Filtering with role user: 
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Jack"
}

Filtering with role hr: 
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Jack",
  "salary": 100000,
  "boss": {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "John",
    "salary": 120000,
    "password": "pwd",
    "rights": {
      "create": true,
      "update": true
    }
  }
}

Filtering with role admin: 
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Jack",
  "salary": 100000,
  "password": "password321",
  "rights": {
    "create": false,
    "update": false
  },
  "boss": {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "John",
    "salary": 120000,
    "password": "pwd",
    "rights": {
      "create": true,
      "update": true
    }
  }
}
```

These question is similar to the question and answer asked with the language golang [GOALNG :Control field visibility depending on User role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42818156/control-field-visibility-depending-on-user-role) but how does it look like in rust?

Answer (score 3):

Complementary to at54321's solution, you don't actually have to duplicate the struct itself, instead you can use [flattening](https://serde.rs/attr-flatten.html) and / or [conditional serialisation skipping](https://serde.rs/attr-skip-serializing.html) e.g.

```rust
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct User {
    id: String,
    name: String,
    #[serde(flatten, skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    _hr: Option<HrView>,
    #[serde(flatten, skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    _admin: Option<AdminView>
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct HrView {
    salary: u32,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    boss: Option<Box<User>>
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct AdminView {
    password: String,
    rights: Rights,
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Rights {
    create: bool,
    update: bool
}
```

demo: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=09fd30ce1f013514d0dc18cf6720f80b

Answer (score 1):

The most commonly used JSON crate in Rust is [serde](https://serde.rs/). One way you can achieve what you want is to create different [`Value`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html)s, depending on user's role (by using the [`json!`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/macro.json.html) macro or by manually creating `Value` instances, for example). Another is to use enums with 3 variants - one variant for each user role (see [Enum representations](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html)).

---

As a side note, I couldn't help but notice you are returning passwords in your JSON. That really looks like a serious security problem and I can hardly think of situations where I would want to return even encoded passwords to the client. Normally, passwords only go "one way": from the client to the server.